# Translate MySQL 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' for Hive

Tags: mysql, hive

With MySQL I can run a simple query to get the create statement of a given table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tableA
```

I want to translate the create statement of a MySQL table into a create statement for Hive.
I do not want to import the table -sqoop- but just recreate its structure in Hive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are trying to achieve the same thing, I took a look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.1-cdh4.1.0/org/apache/sqoop/hive/HiveTypes.java) of sqoop and built my own tool from there.

Answer (score 0):

In [Hive 0.10](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowCreateTable) is same  :

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tableA;
```

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear, I want to translate the create statement of a MySQL table into a create statement for Hive.
I do not want to import the table -sqoop- but just recreate its structure in Hive.